# How to request and hold Wi-Fi connection on Android Wear 2.0

Tags: android, android-wear-2.0

In Android Wear 2.0, if the wearable is connected to the phone via Bluetooth, the system will disconnect Wi-Fi connection automatically to save the battery.

According to Settings->Connectivity->Wi-Fi->About Wi-Fi

> When Wi-fi is enabled, your watch will automatically turn Wi-Fi on or off to save battery.
>   It responds when:
>   ....
>   An app requires Wi-Fi
>   ....

Is there any way for the app to request and hold the Wi-Fi connection?
How to tell the system my app requires Wi-fi right now.

As far as I know, if I turn on the "ADB over WLAN" option, the Wi-Fi connection will be held wherever the Bluetooth is connected.

Comment: AFAIK, wifi disconnecting automatically to save the battery can also be a limitation of your Android wear or phone rather than an issue with the app. Check this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-wear/U06eGXLO-4w) and see if it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is not about the issue of connectivity. The automatically disconnect is a system behavior, I've updated the question description.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Is there an API to do that, aka. locking Wi-Fi?